# Pythonic way of passing combined JSON keys as a parameters to a functions

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, parameters, code-reuse

I wrote a small function that successfully extracts data from a JSON blob.
The blob contains a mixture of lists and dictionaries.
I have no problem accessing the values from the JSON blob if I hard code the keys, but passing the keys as a tuple does not work.

Is there a better way to pass the keys to the function?

Currently my best idea is a write an extract function and pass that.
This seems overly complicated.

Simple example

```
import json

def do_stuff(datablob, mykeys):    

    data = json.loads(datablob)

    for entry in data:

        mydate = entry[u'timestamp'][0:10]
        mytime = entry[u'timestamp'][11:19]

        # this works
        founddata = entry[u'key1'][u'key2'][0][u'key3']

        # this fails 
        founddata = entry[mykeys]

        # do stuff with founddata



if __name__ == '__main__':

    with open('jsonblob.txt','r') as f1:

         mykeys = (u'key1',u'key2',0,u'key3')
         do_stuff(f1.read(), mykeys)
```

Comment: `founddata = entry; for key in mykeys: founddata = founddata[key]`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I'm trying to pass completely different structures to write a resuable function that grabs the required values from a bunch of different json sources...

Comment: ...OK? How does that alter the question? The approach I show above will work with an arbitrary list of keys (and indexes, if there are arrays there). If  the example you've shown doesn't actually represent the problem you're trying to solve, *show one that does*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - On second though I tried this and it actually worked. Hmm. It doesn't have the `entry[mykeys]` bit, where I wanted to pass some object that magically gets the result in one go... - but it does the job. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could have done that first?